# Get latest data at end of every month

Tags: sql, presto

I have running a log of events for a customer as the table below:

| Customer ID | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2023-01-15 | 8000 |
| 2 | 2023-02-07 | 7800 |
| 1 | 2023-03-15 | 2100 |
| 1 | 2023-03-22 | 2200 |
| 1 | 2023-04-07 | 2300 |

I want to get the latest value for each customer at the end of the month. There may be months where there are no updates for a customer, in those cases the latest change could be in previous months.
expected output:

| Customer ID | Month End | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 JAN | 2000 |
| 1 | 2023 FEB | 2000 |
| 1 | 2023 MAR | 2200 |
| 1 | 2023-APR | 2300 |
| 2 | 2023 JAN | 8000 |
| 2 | 2023 FEB | 7800 |
| 2 | 2023 MAR | 7800 |
| 2 | 2023-APR | 7800 |

How do I code this in SQL/presto?

I have been able to use a *where clause* to list the log only till the end of April or the end of March by statically coding month, but not able to get the latest value month by month.

Comment: You need a row for each month therefore you need to generate that series of values first and outer-join it with your data set; having a *calendar table* is a common way of doing this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own set of functions.)